# how to convert a single RBG color to YCbCr color space using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

so I am trying to convert a single RGB colour whose values is (232, 190, 172) to YCbCr color space using [cv2.cvtColor()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) but I get an error stating:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 25
     22 typicalSkinColorRGB = np.array([232, 190, 172])
     24 # convert to YCbCr color space
---> 25 typicalSkinColorYCbCr = cv2.cvtColor(typicalSkinColorRGB, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCR_CB)
     26 print(typicalSkinColorYCbCr)

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x820c46fd::Set<3,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0x820c46fd::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

and this is just a simple a code that I am trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# from researching on the internet, the RGB color (232, 190, 172) is a typical natural skin
typicalSkinColorRGB = np.array([232, 190, 172])

# convert to YCbCr color space
typicalSkinColorYCbCr = cv2.cvtColor(typicalSkinColorRGB, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCR_CB)
print(typicalSkinColorYCbCr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is to do with the shape of your input array.
CV2 wants 3 colour channels, but your array only has a single channel.
Generally, an image will have a shape `[width, height, n_channels]`.
If you change it to `np.array([[[232, 190, 172]]])` it should work - since it will now be a single pixel image so to speak.